# R plotly Choropleth not plotting data

Tags: r, plotly, choropleth

I tried to follow the tutorial on https://plotly.com/r/mapbox-county-choropleth/, but couldn't work out how to use it with another geojson about covid-19 data from the german government.

```
library(plotly)
library(rjson)

url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Johannes96/Coropleth/main/RKI_Corona_Bundeslaender_2.geojson'
geojson <- rjson::fromJSON(file=url)
url2<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Johannes96/Coropleth/main/RKI_Corona_Bundeslaender.csv"
df <- read.csv(url2)
g <- list(
  fitbounds = "locations",
  visible = FALSE
)
fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
  type="choroplethmapbox",
  geojson=geojson,
  locations=df$ObjectId,
  z=df$AnzahlFall,
  colorscale="Viridis",
  featureidkey="properties.OBJECTID_1"
)
fig <- fig %>% colorbar(title = "covid-19 cases germany")
fig <- fig %>% layout(
  mapbox=list(
    style="carto-positron",
    zoom =5,
    center=list(lon=9.7, lat=50))
)
fig
```

The problem is that it doesn't plot the shapes of the geojson file. Tried to find a solution since several hours but it just won't work. Any help or guideline would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The df column you call are false, replace ObjectId by OBJECTID_1 and Fallzahl by AnzahlFall for exemple :

```
library(plotly)
library(rjson)

url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Johannes96/Coropleth/main/RKI_Corona_Bundeslaender_2.geojson'
geojson <- rjson::fromJSON(file=url)
url2<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Johannes96/Coropleth/main/RKI_Corona_Bundeslaender.csv"
df <- read.csv(url2)
g <- list(
  fitbounds = "locations",
  visible = FALSE
)
fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
  type="choroplethmapbox",
  geojson=geojson,
  locations=df$OBJECTID_1,
  z=df$Fallzahl,
  colorscale="Viridis",
  featureidkey="properties.OBJECTID_1"
)
fig <- fig %>% colorbar(title = "covid-19 cases germany")
fig <- fig %>% layout(
  mapbox=list(
    style="carto-positron",
    zoom =5,
    center=list(lon=9.7, lat=50))
)
fig
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, you are right. However, it still wont work. Just showing an empty map. Can you post the entire code from strart to end that you used to get this ooutput? The only warning it shows is "Didn't find a colorbar to modify".

Comment: Just edited it, I previously put only the part to modify, the rest was fine

Comment: Ok. thats weird. Now I executed the code above and it still wont work. I just put the code in RStudio and execute it and when it finished loading it just shows an empty map again... What am I doing wrong here? I guess it is time to give it up...

Comment: hmm strange, what is your `packageVersion("plotly")` `packageVersion("rjson")`? don't give up